# Fanfic where the Force sends Obi-Wan back in time and he saves Siri's life

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, time-travel, fan-fiction, obi-wan-kenobi

I read this ~4 years ago, and the title was shortish.

Basically, Obi-Wan gets sent back in time by the Force, and starts changing history. He saves Siri's life, and starts a relationship with her.

He trains really hard, and eventually gets to the point of being able to  beat Yoda in a fight. I remember at the start of the fight, he takes his long robe off and puts it on the floor, and Yoda tells him to put it back on because it conceals his footwork.

When he fights General Grievous, he crushes all four Magna guards instead of only three, which Grievous is impressed by, and it causes him to fight differently against Kenobi.

I have a feeling he told Yoda about the Sith Lord's identity.

Also, the story was completed and a sequel was started (but I'm not sure if it was finished), at some point, which involved 2 blue Grievous clones which apparently learned from fighting experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I may have found it. In the FanFiction site:

> [*Star Wars : Knight of The Force*](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/8206500/1/Star-Wars-Knight-of-The-Force) » by Dioussis A Siriwan story. Obi-wan
>   is the Knight of the Forceand is sent back in the past to erase the
>   darkness in the galaxy. Can he succeed alone ? Sequel is posted :
>   Titans of Darkness. Due to complaints, now rated M
>
> Star Wars, M, English, Adventure & Romance, chapters: 61, words:
>   409k+, favs: 385, follows: 240, updated: Nov 24, 2013 published: Jun
>   11, 2012, Obi-Wan K., Siri T.

Although there is nothing about Yoda or Grievous in the description.

Comment: Thank you, this is it. (Grievous and the Magna guards happened in chapter 56)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because that link is to the mobile site which does not look good on PCs.